# Curious behaviour while writing to files

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

I have a question about Python's behavior while opening and writing data in files.
I have a large code that is built to run even for hours and it involves writing text in ASCII files. The code uses the `with open` method and keeps a file open during the program's run.
Sometimes I need to stop the execution of the program, thus getting a `Process finished with exit code -1` exit status.

The matter that's bugging me is this curious behavior when the code is running and I get confirmation that text has been written in the ASCII files, but if I stop the code, the files are empty.
Let's have for example, the code below:

```
import time

# Create the .txt files
with open('D:/Stuff/test1.txt', 'w') as write1:
    pass

with open('D:/Stuff/test2.txt', 'w') as write2:
    pass

# Write some text into the.txt files
# Case 1. The code runs until the end
with open ('D:/Stuff/test1.txt', 'a') as infile1:
    a = range(1, 50, 1)
    infile1.write(str(a))
    print "Writing completed!"

# Case 2. I stop the execution manually. I use time.sleep to be able to stop it in this example
with open ('D:/Stuff/test2.txt', 'a') as infile2:
    b = range(1, 50, 1)
    infile2.write(str(b))
    print "Writing completed!"

    print "Start sleep"
    time.sleep(10)

    << At this line I end the script manually>>

    print "End sleep"
```

What happens is that Case 1, the text is written in the files, but in case 2, I get them empty.
Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: Not related, but you dont need the first couple of lines with the 'w'. 'a' creates the file if it doesnt exist

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks! :)

Comment: How did you terminate the script at the given position to bypass the flushing *with* would do automatically?

Comment: I am running the script from PyCharm IDE and stopped the process from there

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you might want to ensure that you're indeed writing to the disk, instead of to a buffer.

One way of doing so is by using `infile2.flush()`:

```
infile2.write(str(b))
infile2.flush() # <- here
print "Writing completed!"
```

A different way is to [open the file with no buffering](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). In the `open` call, set `buffering=0`.

The former method places the onus on you to remember to flush. On the other hand, it gives you greater control of "checkpoints" when to flush. Automatically unbuffered IO has lower throughput, in general.

Comment: Oh, it works. Which method is better to use? Open with buffering or the 'flush()' one?

Comment: @Litwos Added a paragraph at the end. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: I think I will stick with the 'flush()' method for the greater control. Thank you! :)

Comment: a) if this is the correct answer, the problem is independent from python or the with statement. b) I would propose to wrap *with* into a try/finally construct (and put the flush in the finally section), which also cleans up for other sorts of exceptions.

Comment: @guidot Interesting points. I agree with a). Regarding b), it is redundant to put a `flush` there - the `with` closes the file, and that is guaranteed to first flush it.`

Comment: @guidot: I haven't used try/except that much. But I looked up now for try/finally and it's very interesting to use (https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-341.html). I will dive into this. Thank you!